# Mystified by how EnvironmentObject is being updated (or not)

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-environment

I have an EnvironmentObject variable that is being used various places.

I would like to update it using a button with a .alert modifier.

The .alert invokes a func within which the EnvironmentObject updates itself with a name supplied by the .alert modifier.

Puzzle is that within the func the EnvironmentObject seems unchanged.  On the first use, it shows the initialized values.  But when it is used by the Map($...) it does seem to have been updated.  Subsequent uses of the button show that the values within the func are always from the last update.

I want to use the EnvironmentObject elsewhere, but it is always one step behind.

here is the code with some comments.  If there's another way, please suggest.

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct LocationFinderViewCopy: View {
    @EnvironmentObject  var mapAPI: MapAPI  // I am using this elsehwere
    @State private var showingAlert = false
    @State private var locationName = ""
    
    
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Map(position: $mapAPI.locations[0].cameraPosition) {  //$mapAPI shows the most recent update, despite what I see in the findlocation function
                let temp = mapAPI.locations[0].coordinate
                let tempCam = mapAPI.locations[0].cameraPosition.region
                Annotation(mapAPI.locations[0].name, coordinate:  mapAPI.locations[0].coordinate, anchor: .center) {
                    MapMarkerView()
                }
            }
   
            Button("Alert find Button") {
                showingAlert.toggle()
            }
            .alert("Location for find", isPresented: $showingAlert) {
                TextField("location", text: $locationName)
                Button("Cancel", action: doNothing)
                Button("OK", action: findLocation)
            } message: {
                Label("name", systemImage: "circle.circle")
            }
        }
        
    }
    func doNothing() {
    }
    func findLocation() {
        let tempCoord1 = mapAPI.locations[0].coordinate  // mapAPI original intiation
        let tempCam1 = mapAPI.locations[0].cameraPosition  //checking value
        let name = locationName
        mapAPI.getLocation(address: locationName, delta: 10)
        let tempCoord2 = mapAPI.locations[0].coordinate  // expected mapAPI to reflect it is still showing init values.  Each subsequent entry shows the previous request.  same value as tempCoord1
        let tempCam2 = mapAPI.locations[0].cameraPosition
    }
}

#Preview {
    LocationFinderViewCopy()
}
```

Trying to update an EnvironmentObject and the updates appear out of sync

Comment: What does `getLocation` do? Is there an asynchronous (lit. out of sync) operation in there?

Comment: Note, using an index eg `locations[0]` is a recipe for troubles.
 Retructure your code to have just the `.first` element, maybe as a separate var,
 since this is the only one you are interested in.

Comment: If you have `@StateObject private var mapAPI = MapAPI()` in the parent view,
 and passed `mapAPI` to other views using `.environmentObject(mapAPI)`, it **will not be** `...one step behind.`,
the view will be updated with new data. Your tests (and presumably prints) after you call `mapAPI.getLocation(address: locationName, delta: 10)` are the problems, because `getLocation(...)` is asynchronous.
 That is, you need to wait until it has finished before you can print the results. Simply remove those `let tempCoord2 = mapAPI....` etc... after the call, they are useless. Trust the View info.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to use [@Environment](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentvalues) for your API and have a function that returns a location you can store in a state, e.g.

```
@Environment(\.mapAPI) var mapAPI

@State var location: Location
@State var gettingLocation = false

Button(gettingLocation ? "Cancel" : "Get Location") {
    gettingLocation.toggle()
}
.task(id: gettingLocation) {
    if !gettingLocation { return }
    location = await mapAPI.getLocation()
    gettingLocation = false
}
```

This way you can avoid the inconsistency issue typical of objects.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm learning things in a haphazard fashion and am not familiar with the @Environment(.\mapAPI) var mapAPI  construct you suggest.  Naive question, in that line, how is the type of mapAPI known?  I had been using using it as an EnvironmentObject injected at the main level and used throughout the views.  Is your suggestion consistent with this or something entirely different?  BTW, I have a working solution that simply involves using the updated location information outside my function a second button operation.  Works fine but seems clunky.

Comment: Check the link in my answer for an example, look for EnvironmentKey on the page. It's very similar to `EnvironmentObject` but your `MapAPI` is a struct containing your async funcs that return results (throwing exceptions on errors is a good idea too).

Comment: Point well taken on reading the documentation (understanding it will probably also help). 
 In the meantime, @Environment(.\mapAPI) var mapAPI: MapAPI produces compiler error "Expected identifier after '.' expression.  Must be something else missing or needed.

Comment: Actually MapAPI is a class conforming to ObservableObject.  In case that makes a difference.

Comment: change `MapAPI` to a struct, `ObservableObject` is part of `Combine` that is redundant now we have async/await and `.task`

Comment: `@Environment(\.mapAPI)`

Comment: Changing class to a struct created numerous compilation errors.  I think I need to go back and do some major refactoring to get to the bottom of this.  No quick and easy fix (my favorite kind).   Thank you for taking a look.